# How to Get FedEx & UPS Zone numbers if I know the from and to Zip Codes?

Tags: api, web-services, fedex

Other than studying and working with their full APIs...

Is there an easy way to get the shipping zone number from FedEx and UPS if I know the "from" and "to" zip codes?

For example, is there a simple web service that I can use?

Comment: Why not ...use the API? That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you, I have been trying to find the answer for this as well, but it does not see that that information is easily available for us API users. From what I can tell, there is no way to get this information from the APIs themselves. There are workarounds for this though:

**UPS:**
Download the US rate/zone chart from UPS at the following link, after entering your origin zip:
http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/shipping/cost/zones/continental_us.html

International on the other hand is a different story, and I don't know of a way to figure this out.

**FedEx**
You can make a GET request to the following URL, after replacing the origPostalCd, destCountryCd, and destPostalCd parameters with the needed data, then parsing the HTML out. Here is the location table cell before the express zone:

```
<td><img src="http://www.fedex.com/images/ascend/shared/spacer.gif" width="15" height="1"><img src="http://www.fedex.com/images/ascend/shared/shared_sq_express.gif" width="9" height="9" border="0" alt="">&nbsp;<b>Express Zone:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
```

International zones are hit and miss, as it seems some locations (such as Vancouver) don't return a zone.

Answer (score -1):

Both FedEx and UPS have web-services for tracking packages and printing shipping labels etc.

FedEx provides a ready to use sample of accessing their (Tracking) web-service which probably already has the information you need.

UPS, OTOH, doesn't give you sample code, so you must read their spec and parse the xml yourself.

(At least this was true ~6 months ago, when I worked with both API's)